# can't push Object into the array in mongoose/mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I built a simple mongoose schema like the following schema

```
    var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
            user: {type:String, required:true, unique:true},
            msgs: [ 
                     {                  
                        test1:{url:String, name:String},
                        test2:String
                     } 
                   ]
        });

   var model  = mongoose.model('test', schema);
```

Now I tried to insert a document and push some values into the document seen as below

```
  var update = {"$push":
                   {
                     'msgs':
                       { 
                          'test1':{'name':'default id','url':'default url' } ,
                          'test2': 'abc'   
                       }
                   }
                };

   model.update({user:'username'},update,{ upsert: true },function(err,data){
            if(err) console.error(err);
            else console.log(data);     
   });
```

Since the model allows upsert, so the document is inserted successfully, however when I reviewed the created document.
The result is

```
{
    'user': 'username',
    'msgs':[ { 'test2':'abc', '_id':'xxxxxxxxxx' } ]
}
```

It seems to me that I didn't push {test1:{url:'',name:''}} into the array, I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: I suggest you to create another model like "Msg" and set desired fields. Use this Msg model while upserting sub document

Answer (score 0):

You can define separate model for Url and embed it to msgs>test1 field like below;

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
            user: {type:String, required:true, unique:true},
            msgs: [ 
                     {                  
                        test1:Url,
                        test2:String
                     } 
                   ]
        });

var Url = new mongoose.Schema({
    url: {
       type: String
    },
    name: {
       type: String
    }
});
```

var Url = mongoose.model('Url', Url);

While upserting, define an object like;

```
var urlModel = new Url();
urlModel.url = "your_url";
urlModel.name = "your_name";
```

and try upsert operation. This shall be work for you

Comment: why when I tried this solution,  test1:Url,  it throws out a error :  uncaught exception: TypeError: Undefined type at `test1' Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.  I am using mongoose 3.8.2

Comment: I have forgotten to initiate Url model. I tried to show embedded structure by using nested object